# how to enable workflow submodules in Modules administration page

Tags: workflows

I am a very beginner to Drupal. In order to understand how Drupal-Workflow works, I try to install Workflow Module into my site. Following the installation guide on Drupal Documentation, i place the entire workflow directory into your Drupal modules directory, but when i go to the Modules administration page,  and try to enable the following workflow submodules, i get into the trouble, like this, i couldn't check the submodules. So, who can give me a hand, appreciate enough！[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page has suggested you the reason. You didn't install Entity module, you can get this module on [Entity cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module.

This module has no user interface, if you enable it, entities will start being cached, if you disable it, they'll stop.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I have resolved this problem, Thank you very much.

Comment: And I noticed that you didn't install Token too. You can't start **Workflow Notify** if you don't have. Get it on https://www.drupal.org/project/token